# How to plot joint probability distribution of three elements?

Tags: python, matplotlib, probability-density

I have 3 columns of data. I have used **numpy.histogramdd** to find joint probability distribution of these elements. I have used no. of bins = 100. Now I want to plot these using matplotlib. The data now have format of 100X100X100. What is the best way to plot?

Comment: I would recommend looking at the [histogram demo](http://matplotlib.org/1.2.1/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo.html) and [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist). Have you actually tried anything yet?

Comment: Ya I have plotted these earlier, but now I need 3D histogram plot.

Comment: Oh, I see. Have you checked out [this example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/hist3d_demo.html) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061061/how-can-i-render-3d-histograms-in-python ? If those don't solve your problem, can you [edit] and include some code to show where you are having trouble?