# Plot two 2D-data histograms on the same chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I am looking for a way to plot multiple histograms of 2D data, but I could not find any documentation about addressing such a problem.

Plotting multiple **1-dimensional histograms** on a same chart with Matplotlib has been addressed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6871201/plot-two-histograms-on-single-chart-with-matplotlib) and it also covered in [the Matplotlib docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/histogram_multihist.html).

[image]

There are [threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061061/how-can-i-render-3d-histograms-in-python) and documentations that deal with 2D data ([3d plots](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/mplot3d/hist3d.html) or [contours](https://www.python-graph-gallery.com/83-basic-2d-histograms-with-matplotlib)), but for a **single data series**.

[image]
[image]

I could not find any thread/docs on plotting multiple 2D-data histograms on the same chart. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Seaborn's `sns.kdeplot` can work with 2D data showing normalized histograms and use hue to distinguish data.  See the geyser examples at https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain I got the question right, but I don't have any issue with that.
Taken from this [demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/3d_bars.html#sphx-glr-gallery-mplot3d-3d-bars-py):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# set up the figure and axes
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

n_fake_data = 2

for _ in range(n_fake_data):
    
    # fake data
    _x = np.random.randint(0, 10, 4)
    _y = np.random.randint(0, 10, 4)
    _xx, _yy = np.meshgrid(_x, _y)
    x, y = _xx.ravel(), _yy.ravel()

    top = x + y
    bottom = np.zeros_like(top)
    width = depth = 1

    ax.bar3d(x, y, bottom, width, depth, top, shade=True)
    

plt.show()
```

And the result:
[image: Stacked 3D histograms]

Of course, you would have to play with depth / transparency to see both histograms.